# Datarowcollection cannot be converted to string In visual basic

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a system right now in which When I put some value in my first text box (For eg. A primary key), I want the other textboxes to fetch the related data from my database and automatically get filled with it. I'm working on visual basic. I am new to this. For some Reason, it keeps on telling me that datarowcollection cannot be converted to string. Please help me get his working.
Here is the code:-

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\admin\Documents\Asset_Manager.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim StrCmd As String = "Select * from Asset_Master where Asset_Id= '" & txt_allocate_asset_id.Text & "' "
        Dim Command As SqlCommand
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Try
            Cn.Open()
            Command = New SqlCommand(StrCmd, Cn)
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            da.Fill(dt)
            txt_demo_model_no.Text = dt.Rows[0][model_no].ToString()//The error line
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Actual code samples would help with troubleshooting this.

Comment: I am trying to upload a pic but was unable to for some reason. I'll try again

Comment: How does this website work? I'm using it for the first time. I am not able to post a pic nor am I able to put in the code, please help

Comment: Code formatting is accomplished by indenting the entire block by 4 spaces. See [the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. So there you go i hope  you got the code properly.